# hashing redirected DOS output

Tags: c++, sha

I'm trying to hash the result of a command line parameter using SHA1 from openssl and it works fine. the problem is that i need to compare this result from other that i got from SHA1 PHP function, and the result that i get is not the same. when i try to hash with a fix parameter lets say "police" the result is the same, so i think the problem is that the result that i get from DOS console is encoded with Unicode or ASCII.

this is how i get DOS result

```
std::string exec(char* cmd) {
FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
char buffer[128];
std::string result = "";
while(!feof(pipe)) {
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
        result += buffer;
}
_pclose(pipe);
return result;
}
```

everything works fine and i'm able to hash the data i got from result.

```
std::string tag = exec_result.substr (found+2,11);
SHA1((unsigned char *)tag.c_str(), strlen(tag.c_str()), temp);
```

the problem is that the hashed value is not the same i got from PHP SHA1 function, so i thought may be the implementation of both functions were no the same, but then i tried the SHA1 C++ function with a fixed parameter and the results were equals, so i think the difference may be on the characters set of the output i'm getting from DOS console. can somebody please helpme

Comment: Maybe using a debugger to inspect the contents of the tag string could reveal something?

Comment: Yes that's what i did, and i realize that there was one extra space i haven't noted. Once i've deleted that space from my string the results from both functions (C++ and PHP) where the same. Thanks for your time and your help

Answer (score 2):

See if this is related to the [newline conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). UNIX is using `LF` whereas DOS/Windows is using `CR/LF`.

Try it on a single string with no newline/linefeed characters first and if it works, add logic to "standardize" your data..

Comment: thanks Alexander, the problem was an extra space i haven't noticed